# Word 2010 does not save as Word 2003 XML

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document which was created in Word 2010, but for use in a particular application, it needs to be saved in Word 2003 XML format.  When I try the normal "Save as" via the File menu (choosing Word 2003 XML format to save as), Word 2010 thinks for a while, and then presents the "Save as" dialog to me again, suggesting that I save the document as .docx.

Trying to get around this, I saved the document as .doc (i.e. Word 97-2003 document).  This worked fine.  But when I try to save this .doc file as Word 2003 XML, again Word 2010 thinks for a while, and then presents the "Save as" dialog, suggesting this time that I save the document as .doc.

Oh, and I need to say that this only happens on a specific document - all others work fine.  I know I should try a process of elimination and see what is causing the symptoms, but it would nice to have an answer "in principle".

Is there perhaps a setting somewhere that I have enable?  Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: Yes, I guess so - I edited the question to show that it only happens one one document, not on others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I deleted pages at the end of the document until the problem went away. I then found hidden characters (0x202b = Right-To-Left Embedding, and 0x202E = Right-To-Left Override).

When I removed all of these characters, the problem disappeared and I could save the file as a 2003 xml file. However, when I removed these characters, the word/character order changed with multiple words or words containing non-Hebrew characters.

With Word 2007, I had no problem saving the file as XML 2003. I could then open, edit and save the XML 2003 file in Word 2010.

Comment: I have indicated this as the answer, because it makes sense.  I can't say it's the definitive answer in my case, because I can't remember any more which document it was that exhibited this behaviour.